# Jackson serialize NULL property value if Include.NON_NULL is set at class level

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have a model class like this:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Defect
```

and I need `JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL` to ignore the `null` values. But I have a property that needs to be `null` sometimes.

```
@JsonProperty("blocked")
private String blocked;
```

Is there a way I can dynamically (at run-time) set this value to be included or not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to override the class-level `@JsonInclude` with a field-level `@JsonInclude`, as follows:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
@JsonProperty("blocked")
private String blocked;
```